# Lisp Error: Origin 9614327 is not in the stack of NIL

Tags: emacs, lisp

I've been running into a rather strange error when I run my LISP code:

```
Origin 9614327 is not in the stack of NIL
```

I'm running the code on Lispbox Emacs. When I try to look at the stack trace in Emacs, it freezes. C-c C-c and ESC-ESC-ESC don't get it out.

The code seems to be taking an extremely long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a result of an infinite recursion cycle. I had a function `known-c` that sometimes called another function `expand`. `expand` sometimes called a function `known-c`, and when the conditions for both to call each other were met, they loop infinitely. Why this causes the error above, I don't know, but I solved the issue by simply removing the loop.